# How to use ISNULL in jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a table test1 having a column amount.I want to to retrieve the summation of all the columns.So I am using SUM function like this

```
SELECT SUM(cda.amount)FROM test cda
```

If the table is empty then it gives me null

The equivalent JPA code is as follows

If there is n

```
public Double sumAmount()
    {
        Query query=entityManagerUtil.getQuery("SELECT SUM(cda.amount)FROM test cda");

        Object result=query.getSingleResult();
        return (Double)result;
    }
```

Now In my controller I am adding this amount to principal;

```
Double total=prinicipal+daoImpl.sumAmount();
```

As `sumAmount()` returns `null` so I am getting NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION while adding here `prinicipal+daoImpl.sumAmount();`

So I am thinking to return 0 if the amount is null so tried ISNULL and IFNULL both like this

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(cda.amount),0) FROM test cda
```

but here it gives me the following error

```
No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.MethodNode 
 \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'ISNULL' {originalText=ISNULL}
```

So can anybody please tell me how to use properly ISNULL in JPA

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The JPQL equivalent to the **ISNULL** or **NVL** commands is the **COALESCE** command.
So you can use `SELECT COALESCE(SUM(cda.amount),0) FROM test cda`.