# Spring Data JPA aggregate functions on an empty resultset

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, h2

I am working on a project involving `Spring` and `JPA/Hibernate`. The database driver used in my development environment is `H2`. My application has a page that displays statistics, one example of such a statistic is the average age of my users. However, when I try to fetch the average age using `JPQL`, I receive an exception

```
Result must not be null!
```

Assume for simplicity reasons that I store age as an `integer` on every `User` object (in my application this is of course not the case, but that's not important for my problem).

**User model**

```
@Entity
public class User implements Identifiable<Long> {
    private int age;
    // more fields and methods, irrelevant
}
```

**User repository**

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT AVG(u.age) FROM #{#entityName} u")
    long averageAge();
}
```

I cannot seem to figure out why calling `UserRepository#averageAge();` is throwing the exception. I have tried replacing the function `AVG` in the query by `COUNT` and this behaves as expected. I have also tried to use an SQL query and setting `nativeQuery = true` in the annotation, yet to no avail. I can ofcourse solve it by fetching all the users and calculate the average age in plain Java, but this wouldn't be very efficient.

**Stacktrace:**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Result must not be null!
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.MethodInvocationValidator.invoke(MethodInvocationValidator.java:102)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy150.averageAge(Unknown Source)
    at my.test.application.StatisticsRunner.run(StatisticsRunner.java:72)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:809)
    ... 30 more
```

**Solved**

The exception was caused by the fact that `AVG()` returns `null` when performed on an empty table. I fixed it by modifying the query (inspired by [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27329843/how-to-use-isnull-in-jpa)) as follows:

```
@Query("SELECT coalesce(AVG(u.age), 0) FROM #{#entityName} u")
long averageAge();
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: @Aris_Kortex added the stack trace (the missing part is Failed to load ApplicationContext; not relevant for the error I suppose)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the `EmptyResultDataAccessException` exception is thrown when a result from a query was expected to have at least one row (or element) but none was returned.

Related documentation about this can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/EmptyResultDataAccessException.html).

I would suggest to run the same query this attempts to run in order to further validate this theory. Now the good question's what to do with this.

You have two options. Either catch the `EmptyResultDataAccessException` exception at your calling point and handle it directly in there or alternatively you can have an `ExceptionHandler` which will be tasked with handling such exceptions.

Both ways of handling this, should be OK and you may choose between each depending on your scenario.

Comment: I went with the first option, since it's not really an exception; when there are no values it should simply return 0 and writing a catch-all exception handler wouldn't always fit the case. Thanks!

Comment: Nice. Yes indeed the way of signaling that the results of a query are empty using an exception is quite dumb for me. Ideally, I would change the signature to `Long` instead of the primitive and just return null in case no results are found. I think that `null` is a better logical representation of an empty result set instead of returning 0. For example consider what would happen if you had records whose average age was 0? Hence the object and a null check should be a better option all together. Just delegate this action to the service and let callers perform the null check.

Comment: Using `Long` instead of `long` gives the same exception however

Comment: A better solution would probably be to use some construct like `SELECT ISNULL(SUM(u.age), 0)` yet I'm unsure whether H2 supports this

Comment: Turns out is is supported https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27329843/how-to-use-isnull-in-jpa

Comment: NVL2 could also work for you in this case I think. http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#nvl2

Comment: COALESCE could also be an option http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#coalesce

Comment: If you will extend jparepositorty and set result to optional long. Still same error or will be null ?

Comment: thats a very stupid way to handle empty results, the spring is the one to blame.

Answer (score 6):

If you use Spring Data, and if your method returns `null` when Hibernate can't find a match, make sure you add `@org.springframework.lang.Nullable` to your method signature:

```
public interface SomeRepositoryCustom {
    @org.springframework.lang.Nullable
    public Thing findOneThingByAttr(Attribute attr) {
        /* ...your logic here... */
    }
}
```

This is because Spring Data checks the nullability of your method, and if the annotation is missing, it's going to enforce that you always need to return an object:

```java
/* org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.MethodInvocationValidator */

@Nullable
@Override
public Object invoke(@SuppressWarnings("null") MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
    /* ...snip... */

    if (result == null && !nullability.isNullableReturn()) {
        throw new EmptyResultDataAccessException("Result must not be null!", 1);
    }

    /* ...snip... */
```

I used Spring Boot version `2.1.1.RELEASE` and Spring Data `2.1.4.RELEASE`.

Answer (score 0):

i am not complete sure, but i think the problem it is because of the type of return long, maybe you should use the Long wrapper, long does not allow null because it is a primitive, try to change to

```
@Query("SELECT AVG(u.age) FROM #{#entityName} u")
Long averageAge();
```

Comment: Please read up on the documentation regarding the exception itself and you'll understand why you get this.